# How to use Smote with imblearn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am not able to use SMOTE with imblearn. below is what i am doing in my jupyter notebook. Any suggestions?

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
#installs successfully
!python -V
#2.7.6
imblearn.__version__
#0.3.0
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE()
```

here it throws the error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-0715e331ee1b> in <module>()
      1 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
----> 2 sm = SMOTE()

/home/pradeep/Envs/nyraml/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imblearn/over_sampling/smote.pyc in __init__(self, ratio, random_state, k, k_neighbors, m, m_neighbors, out_step, kind, svm_estimator, n_jobs)
    164                  svm_estimator=None,
    165                  n_jobs=1):
--> 166         super(SMOTE, self).__init__(ratio=ratio, random_state=random_state)
    167         self.kind = kind
    168         self.k = k

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
    enter code here
```

Comment: The latest version is `0.3.3`. Maybe try upgrading to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install imblearn using Anaconda prompt and not using traditional pip method. Faced the same issue myself and had to go looking for a solution.